# How to integrate Karma with Rails asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-pipeline, karma-runner

I would like to use the Karma test runner in my AngularJS + Rails project. Has anyone integrated them successfully? More specifically, I'm interested to know how to integrate with the asset pipeline (I have files with extension `.coffee.erb`, which would need to be preprocessed twice).

I use Karma version 0.10.1 and Rails 4.

Any help / examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

I have been struggling with marking Karma aware of Sprockets in my rails app, and manage to come with a solution. You need a rake task to get the list of assets declare in your `application.js`, and inject them in the `files` array of your Karma configuration file.

In my rake task I have this:

```
sprockets = Rails.application.assets
sprockets.append_path Rails.root.join("spec/karma")
files = Rails.application.assets.find_asset("application_spec.js").to_a.map {|e| e.pathname.to_s }
```

along with my karma configuration file:

```
files: [
  APPLICATION_SPEC,
  'app/assets/javascripts/angular/*/*.{coffee,js}',
  'spec/javascripts/**/*_spec.{coffee,js}'
]
```

where I replace `APPLICATION_SPEC` with all the sprocket `files`. I wrote a [tutorial](http://sebastien.saunier.me/blog/2014/02/04/angular--rails-with-no-fuss.html) if you want the big picture.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't integrated them as such, but for my project I've chosen to go the other way, and serve each entirely separately.  So I've created a rails app and an angular app in separate directories, then I've sym-linked the angular app into the public directory of the rails app so that the rails server will serve up the angular scripts and templates.

My logic in doing it this way was that I didn't want two different pre-processors in the same set of code, and I wasn't confident that the testing tools would play nice with each other.  I've also chosen to use the build scripts that came with ng-boilerplate, and those scripts are doing quite a bit of work that otherwise would be done by rake or other tools.

I've been writing a tutorial series based around that, it can be found here: http://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/08/11/rails-app-for-angularjs-simple-application/

Answer (score 1):

Some of the alternatives that I have seen so far:

- Define your erb files in Karma config, might work for simple cases. (from http://jaketrent.com/post/import-erb-into-karma/)
- Build the rails app with Middleman and use a Karma config based on the Middleman output
- Use http://localhost:port/assets/application.js in Karma config rather than directly referring to the files (http://danott.co/posts/rails-javascript-testing-using-karma.html)
- Use/adapt karma.rake task of Sebastien (http://sebastien.saunier.me/blog/2014/02/04/angular--rails-with-no-fuss.html)
- Use a karma plugin to fill in the gap (Seen the following so far: [karma-sprockets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-sprockets), https://github.com/steel/karma-sprockets-mincer)

Answer (score 0):

I got Karma and Angular to play nice by doing the following:

Add to your `development.rb` file:

`config.assets.prefix = "/dev-assets"`

This will precompile your assets into `public/dev-assets` folder, the same way production will go to `public/assets`. You can then add to your karma config:

```
files: [
    ...
    './public/dev-assets/*.js'`,
    ...
];
```